# Ajax fails every time when trying to use password_hash in php file

Tags: php, ajax, password-encryption

Ajax fails when I try to use either `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functionalities in php script.

So I wrote a html login form, a javascript and a php file to perform login function. I use Ajax to send the data captured in the form to the php in order to perform verification. However, Ajax fails when I try to use either `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` in php script.

**javascript:**

```
alert("??");

function submitLoginData(){

alert("open");

var allTheData = $("#loginSection").serialize();

alert(allTheData);

$.ajax({

    url:"hash.php",
    type:"post",
    data: allTheData,
    success: function(response){
        alert("??????");
        alert(response);

    }
  });
}
```

**php:**

```
<?php 
     $a = 1+1;
     echo "running";
     $vari = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf",PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

?>
```

I expect the php script can peform `password_verify` and echo different strings so that I can change the html based on the authorization result.

Comment: This is confusing, you are posting a data to php file then what?  Your php file is not catching the `POSTED` datas.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: *"Ajax fails"* - Hoe does it fail? Do you get error messages? What are they?